# Escaping from loop for line in file but still get the rest of the file as string

Tags: python, nested-loops, getline

The following code gets each line from a txt file.  If the line is "References\n" the file should continue to getlines, but appended to another string removing the subsequent '\n' instances.  How should I deal with the nested loops and breaks?

```
for file in os.listdir(txtdir):
    if file <> '.DS_Store':
        linenum = 1
        refindicator = 0
        AppendixCheck = 0
        print 'Opening ' + str(file) + '...'
        for line in open(txtdir + file):
            if AppendixCheck == 0:
                #take title from the first line
                if linenum == 1:
                    title = line.replace(",","")
                    print "Title: " + title
                linenum +=1
                #checking for "references\n" line
                if line == "References\n":
                    refindicator +=1
                #after references are found
                if line =='Appendix\n':
                    AppendixCheck +=1
                if refindicator >0:
                    reflist += getline().replace('\n','')
                #reflist = line.split(',')
        print reflist
```

Comment: Your code sample is not valid Python. `for line:` is invalid, and your indentation is incorrect.

Comment: It's a good practice to use [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4) when working with files in Python.

Comment: its hard to understand the logic of your code with the wrong indentation. Please correct it so that we can help.

Comment: the problem here is with the if the refindicator is >0: getline()

Comment: Also, `<>` is deprecated, use `!=` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found:

```
for file in os.listdir(txtdir):
    if file <> '.DS_Store':
        linenum = 1
        refindicator = 0
        AppendixCheck = 0
        refdump = ''
        title = ''
        print 'Opening ' + str(file) + '...'
        for line in open(txtdir + file):
            #The first blank line marks the end of the title
            if line == '\n':
                linenum +=1
            #Only works until appendix is breached
            if AppendixCheck == 0:
                #take title from the first line
                if linenum == 1:
                    title += line.replace('\n','').replace(',','').replace('  ', '')
                    print "Title: " + title
                #checking for "references\n" line
                if line == "References\n":
                    refindicator +=1
                #after references are found
                if 'Appendix' in line:
                    AppendixCheck +=1
                if refindicator >0:
                    refdump += line.replace('\n','')
        reflist = refdump.split(',')
        print reflist
```